# How to conditionally create object property in one line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to create a property on an object conditionally.
The idea is to ensure the property **doesn't exist** (so not just null) if it has no value.

What I'm doing right now:

```js
// comes from users
req.query = {
  foo: true
}

// my object which will contains allowed properties IF EXISTS
const where = {}

if (req.query.foo) {
  where.foo = req.query.foo
}
if (req.query.bar) {
  where.bar = req.query.bar
}

console.log(where)
```

It's really boring to repeat this for every different property...

Is there a way to do it in one line?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to get all properties from `req.query`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create object property obj.foo if value exists (or any other condition)

`&&` operator returns second element if the first boolean condition is fulfilled

es6 spread operator `...` does what it does)

```js
const value = 'bar'

const empty = undefined

const obj = {
  ...value && { foo: value }, // read ...(value && { foo: value }) parenthesis are not necessary
  ...empty && { empty },
  ...(100 > 0) && { condition: 'true' },
  ...(100 < 0) && { condition: 'false' },
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Sorry... can you explain it ?

Comment: Create object property conditionally `const value` exists so `obj.foo` is created, `const empty` is `undefined` so the property `obj.empty` is not created

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear for me that the spread operator has effect on the right side of the && operator

Comment: @mbesson Yeah, sorry, there is even an eslint rule which adds parenthesis so Its more clear)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```js
const merged = {...where, ...req.query};
```

Comment: Thx but req.query contains additional properties and I don't want them in merged

Comment: So then you probably want to use moustafa's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const elements = ["foo", "bar"];

elements.forEach(el => {
    if (req.query[el]) {
        where[el] = req.query[el];
    }
});
```

Comment: This forces us to create an array of keys and keep it updated, which doesn't look good

Comment: @NikitaMazur You need to know which keys you're interested in and that is going to be somewhere, why not in a list in one place?

Comment: @BenStephens you're right, you need to keep track of the keys anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it in one line like this :

```js
let where = {};
if (req.query.foo) where = {...where, foo : req.query.foo };
if (req.query.bar) where = {...where, bar : req.query.bar };
```

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple one liner (maybe less readable), you can do:

```js
Object.keys(req.query).forEach(key => req.query[key] && (where[key] = req.query[key]));
```

Comment: if req.query.key = undefined, it will create where.key = undefined

Comment: added a check for that

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay adding a pluck function, you could do it like this:

```js
const req = { query: { baz: '1', foo: '3' } };
const where = {};

const pluck = (keys, obj) =>
  keys.reduce((a, k) => typeof obj[k] === 'undefined' ? a : Object.assign(a, { [k]: obj[k] }), {});

const add_foo_bar = (where, query) =>
  Object.assign({}, where, pluck(['foo', 'bar'], query));

const res = add_foo_bar(where, req.query);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think this is the cleaner solution but I was searching for a solution without adding a function